# C# can't open html file

Tags: c#, html, file

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
   var x = File.Exists(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\page_1.html");
   var y = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\page_1.html");
   var z = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\page_1.html");    
}
```

I debug my code and add my variables to watch and it says "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context" and so on for other two. I know the file exists because if I change name to something else it will throw file not found.

Why is this happening? Is it a stupid mistake I'm not seeing or could something be wrong with the file?

Comment: Please give us some more code. Esp the context in which you execute it. Just tested it in Linqpad with an html file on my desktop. Works fine.

Comment: Literally first lines of console application

Comment: *When I go into debug none of the 3 variables exist in the context?* , what does this mean ? can you please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, but what's the *rest* of the code? Where do you try to use x, y and z? Where does it actually say they don't exist in the context?

Comment: Is you Windows User actually named 'user'?

Comment: I debug my code and add my variables to watch and it says   "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context" and so on for other two

Comment: The context is where the application breaks. Where is your breakpoint set?

Comment: @MPatel no,but I changed it just here. Also if I change the name of the file to soemthing that doesn't exist it throws file not found, but it doesn't throw it for this one.

Comment: @J.Steen on the next line which is just int i; so I can set breakpoint there

Comment: This code works just fine for me, is there any other code you have that you have not posted here?

Comment: No, everything else is after this code. Could it be that something is wrong with the file? I can open it normally in notepad++ or chrome

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try like this :

```
string filePath=@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\page_1.html"
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
 // read your file
}
else
{
 Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
}
```

Comment: It's false, but why is my var x not found in the context? Shouldn't it be false? Also File.ReadAllText doesn't throw an exception, but if I remove the "1" from the name it will say file not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write(x);
```

When I added that line x was finally visible in watch. But still no idea why it was needed.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand why you need all these variables. You don't use 'x' or 'z' anywhere in your code. All you need to do is what @Arshad is doing is his answer.

Comment: But it wasn't working because the file exists but I wasn't able to read it. Only after I used var x somewhere it became visible, before that I couldn't even see x in watch

Comment: Then its a workflow issue in your program, the code you have posted is just fine. Post ALL the code you have if you want more help. As far as everyone is concerned here there is nothing else we can suggest unless you give us that.

Comment: I wanted to see content of variables in watch but wasn't able with that code. That was the problem. There really isn't any other code for now, I just wanted to see what I would get from that file. And I still don't understand why I can't do it without using those variables somewhere. That isn't how it's supposed to work, right?